# I wish to plot the output of a df.mean()

Tags: python, pandas

Please how do i plot the output of the mean of columns. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE9cG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the graph of df.mean() `import matplotlib as plt` and then do `df.mean().plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'Store': ['storeA', 'storeB', 'storeC', 'storeD', 'storeE'],
    'Mean': [5865.480, 6756.710, 4942.105, 5431.405, 2580.025]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot df
df.plot(kind='bar', x='Store', y='Mean', color='red', xlabel='Store', ylabel='Value')

plt.show()
```

[image: bar graph of means]